# syntax error, unexpected end of file in php

Tags: php, database, web

```html
<?php 
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("could not connect to server".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("khader",$conn) or die ("could not connect to database".mysql_error());
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$Usname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['Uname']);
$Pd = mysql_escape_string($_POST['psd']);
if(!$_POST['Uname']||!$_POST['psd']);
{
echo "please fill the required fields before you login" ;
exit();
}
$query = <<<EOF
select * from person where 'uname' = '$Usname' and 'pswd' = '$pd';
EOF;
$query_result= mysql_query($query) or die ("cannot be connected".mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
{
header("logged.php");
}
else
{
echo "wrong username and password" ;
}
mysql_close($conn) or die ("disconnect failed.".mysql_error());
?>
```

this is the program that throws the error !! 
i've tried most of things i know to correct it but there is know improvement at all ..
please help me and thanks alot !!!

Comment: Your first if statement is not close. close it.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh - and that is why indenting your code is useful.

Comment: there is still an error saying that wrong username and password even tho it gave the correct username and password in the database

Comment: khader please mark and up-vote the answer for others help. thanks

Comment: No response from the OP's even after asking. frustrating, deleting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close all if's:

```
<?php 
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("could not connect to server".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("khader",$conn) or die ("could not connect to database".mysql_error());
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$Usname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['Uname']);
$Pd = mysql_escape_string($_POST['psd']);
if(!$_POST['Uname']||!$_POST['psd']);
{
echo "please fill the required fields before you login" ;
exit();
}
$query = <<<EOF
select * from person where 'uname' = '$Usname' and 'pswd' = '$pd';
EOF;
$query_result= mysql_query($query) or die ("cannot be connected".mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
{
header("logged.php");
}
else
{
echo "wrong username and password" ;
}
mysql_close($conn) or die ("disconnect failed.".mysql_error());
} // <-- you forgot this
?>
```